Send multi events to google calendar
I have a course calendar app (nodejs) and I want to send mail with attachment that add all the meetings to google calendar.
I know there is an option to add single event
But can i send multi events?
Of course, I don't have the access privileges to the email's account, but only to send an attachment of an assimilation
Is this task possible?


if you don't have access you cant be using the google calendar api.

Yes, it is possible to send an email with an attachment that contains multiple events to be added to Google Calendar. You can achieve this by creating an iCalendar (.ics) file that includes all the events. When the recipient opens the .ics file, the events will be added to their Google Calendar.

I'll check it, thanks

Since you won't be able to use the Google Calendar API as pointed out in the comments, the Import events to Google Calendar article should be able to help out with the answer's recommendation. It shows how to create files compatible with Google Calendar, and you may also give it to your users so that they may know the steps on how to upload it to their calendar.
